# I have multiplied users on joined request

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel 6 app I have multiplied users getting users with related spatie/persmissions,
as I need filter on selected permission and to show names of user's permissions :
I make as :

```
$users = User
    ::getByName($this->filter_name)
    ->getByStatus($this->filter_status)
    ->leftJoin('model_has_permissions', 'model_has_permissions.model_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->getByUserPermission($this->filter_user_permission, 'model_has_permissions')
    ->getByUserPermissionModelType( 'model_has_permissions')
    ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)
    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($backend_items_per_page)
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate($backend_items_per_page);

$users->getCollection()->transform(function ($user) {
    $permissions_text= '';
    $permissions  = $user->permissions;
    foreach( $permissions as $nextPermission ) {
        $permissions_text.= $nextPermission->name . ', ';
    }
    $user->permission_text = MyFuncsClass::trimRightSubString( $permissions_text, ', ' );
    return $user;
});
```

I expected that using of

```
 ->distinct()
```

would salve it m but I failed. 
Why?

**UPDATED BLOCK :**
Code with whereHas :

```
->whereHas('permissions', function ($query): void {
    $query->where('id', $this->filter_user_permission);
})
```

works ok if $this->filter_user_permission is not empty. In case it is empty. It does not work.
That is backend listing form, so $this->filter_user_permission) can be filled or empty.
To salve it I used next scope:

```
public function scopeGetByUserPermission($query, $permission_id= null, $table_name)
{
    if (!empty($permission_id)) {
        if ( is_array($permission_id) ) {
            $query->whereIn($table_name.'.permission_id', $permission_id);
        } else {
            $query->where($table_name.'.permission_id', $permission_id);
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

It was used in my original post.

I tried to use it as :

```
->whereHas('permissions', function ($query): void {
    $query->getByUserPermission($this->filter_user_permission, 'model_has_permissions');
})
```

but got error : 
Call to undefined method

> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getByUserPermission()

If there is a valid way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scope method "scopeGetByUserPermission" defined in your User model, but in the "whereHas" method $query variable related to Permission model.

If You want to use some scope in your Model, try this.

```
public function scopeGetByUserPermission($query, $permission_id=null/**, $table_name */)
{
    if (!empty($permission_id)) {
        $query->whereHas('permissions', function ($query) use ($permission_id): void {
            /** Cast your $permission_id variable to array and use "whereIn" method */
            $query->whereIn('permission_id', (array)$permission_id);
        });
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Also you can use php7 features for arguments in your scope method

```
public function scopeGetByUserPermission($query, array $permission_id=[])
{
    /** Your scope logic from the code above */
}
```

And calling this scope will be looking like so

```
$users = User
    ::getByName($this->filter_name)
    ->getByStatus($this->filter_status)
    ->getByUserPermission((array)$this->filter_user_permission)
    ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)
    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($backend_items_per_page)
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate($backend_items_per_page);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using "spatie/laravel-permission" package, You may do it like so:

```
$users = User
    ::getByName($this->filter_name)
    ->getByStatus($this->filter_status)
/** ->leftJoin('model_has_permissions', 'model_has_permissions.model_id', '=', 'users.id') */
/** I don't really know what this 2 methods below does
    ->getByUserPermission($this->filter_user_permission, 'model_has_permissions') 
    ->getByUserPermissionModelType( 'model_has_permissions') */
    ->whereHas('permissions', function ($query): void {
        /** Change "permission_field" here to column which you use (example: id,name) from the "permissions" table of your database */
        $query->where('permission_field', $this->filter_user_permission);
    })
    ->orderBy($this->order_by, $this->order_direction)
    ->offset($limit_start)
    ->take($backend_items_per_page)
    ->distinct()
    ->paginate($backend_items_per_page);
```

I hope this help for You

Comment: Thanks, looks like it works. Could you please give some explanations on the decision. Is it "spatie/laravel-permission only decision ?

Comment: If you mean "whereHas" method. This is a Laravel Eloquent Builder method, it works equal for all relationships, the first argument it is name of the relationship method in your model, in this case User model, the package "spatie/laravel-permission" has a trait which you added into your User model

Comment: "Permissions" relationship is defined into this trait

Comment: Thanks! Please look at UPDATED BLOCK :